# python function parameter evaluation model

Tags: python, lambda, evaluation, callable

I was looking at an article on Peter Norvig's website, where he's trying to answer the following question (this is not my question, btw)
 "Can I do the equivalent of (test ? result : alternative) in Python?"

here's one of the options listed by him,

```
def if_(test, result, alternative=None):
    "If test is true, 'do' result, else alternative. 'Do' means call if callable."
    if test:
        if callable(result): result = result()
        return result
    else:
        if callable(alternative): alternative = alternative()
        return alternative
```

And here's a usage example.

```
>>> fact = lambda n: if_(n <= 1, 1, lambda: n * fact(n-1))
>>> fact(6)
720
```

I understand how this works (I think), but I was just playing with the code, and decided to see what happens when I change the third argument in the definition of 'fact' above to 
n * fact(n-1), that is, change it to a non-callable expression. On running it, the interpreter goes into a never ending loop. I have a pretty good idea of why that is happening, that is, the if_ function is returning back the same expression that it is receiving. But what is the type of that expression? What exactly is going on here? I am not looking for a detailed explanation , but just for some pointers to python's evaluation model which might help my understanding.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably unrelated but you can just use `result if test else alternative`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the loop never terminates when you change `fact` to `n * fact(n-1)` is that `n * fact(n-1)` has to evaluate first (as the third argument to `if`).  Evaluating it leads to another call to `fact`, ad infinitum (since there is no longer any base case to stop it).

Previously, you were passing a function object (`lambda`), which would not be evaluated until the body of `if`, and its result would be checked via `test`.

This is known (I believe) as eager evaluation, where function arguments are evaluated before they are passed to the function.  In a lazy-evaluation scheme, the arguments would not be evaluated until they were used in the function body.

Comment: If n<=1 would be evaluated correctly, the recursion would stop at n = 1, returning 1.

Comment: `n <= 1` will be evaluated, but its value is never checked until inside the function body.  When he uses a recursive expression instead of a lambda as the third parameter, the function body is never reached.

Comment: I wasn't arguing that it computes n!, I just misunderstood your answer. Now, I read it once more and I agree with it.

Comment: @fsm - you're welcome.  If you found this answer to be helpful, I'd appreciate if you marked it as accepted.